# Update Ubuntu 11.10 without internet connection

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

I'm completely new to Ubuntu 11.10 oneric ocelot desktop i386 plus no internet connection. I have a freshly install of Ubuntu and I want to install ClockWorkMod tether to have internet connection thru my smartphone(via USB), but in order to do that, I need to run a .sh file.

I have readed online that I need a bunch of things to install it, like build-essential, g++ compiler... and a lot of things.

I would like to download all software needed on Windows (I got windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10) and installed using a usb thumb or a cd, since I got internet connection on Windows.

What's the best(easiest) way to do that? or any tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

One guide to installing this particular application is at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941773

Take a look at the aptoncd or apt-zip packages for easier package management of offline systems.

At a minimum, you'll need the libssl-dev and make packages, plus their trees of dependencies. So try an 'apt-get --simulate install libssl-dev make' to get the list of packages you need to download from http://packages.ubuntu.com and install.

The specific answer to your "How do I upgrade offline" question has two parts, and you need both parts together for a successful upgrade. First, the Alternate CD image has upgrade packages for the default install. Second, keep that list of other packages handy, and download the latest versions of them all into an apt-zip or apt-on-cd repo. When you upgrade, the system needs both sets of packages handy.